# How to reverse an array in assembly language ARM?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, reverse

(The problem is based on assembly language ARM.)
I'm dealing with a problem which asking me to reverse a given array.
Just like this:

```
       Given array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
       Reversed array: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

And the limitation of this problem is that I'm only supposed to use registers r0-r3.

I have a basic algorithm, but I'm really confused when I'm trying to implement the idea.
My algorithm:

```
Loop:
      1. get value from head pointer, ptr++
      2. get value from tail pointer, ptr--
      3. swap them
      4. check if head pointer and tail pointer cross,
         if so, exit loop and return.
         if not, go back to loop.
```

But I just don't know how to use only 4 registers to solve this problem..

Below would be all I have currently.

```
.text
.global reverse

reverse:
    @ See if head and tail ptr cross
    @ If so, end loop (b end)

head:
    @ use r2 to represent head value
    ldr r2,[r0]     @ r2 <-*data get the first value

tail:
    @ mov r1,r1     @ size
    sub r1,r1,#1    @ size-1
    lsl r1,r1,#2    @ (size-1)*4
    add r0,r0,r1    @ &data[size-1]      need to ldr r1,[r0] to get value
    ldr r1,[r0]     @ get value for r1 (from tail)

swap:
    @ swap values
    mov r3, r1      @store value to r3
    str r2, [r0] 
    @ head ptr ++
    @ tail ptr --
    @ back to reverse

end:
    @ loop ends
```

Comment: You algorithm is incomplete, it will swap head and tail values forever.

Comment: why don't you try to compile this in C, then disassemble it and study... this is what I do when I wanna know what's under the hood

Comment: after the edit your algorithm will forever swap head+1 and tail-1 values (if they even exists .. and if the word `ptr` means that particular head/tail pointer and not something completely different) ... you should write it down properly (will require a bit more than 4 steps) .. and actually don't hesitate to write it down into simple and simpler steps, it may turn out really helpful for the asm writing.

Comment: I mean, how can you know you have problem to fit into 4 registers, if you don't even know which values you need (that algorithm description is not exact enough.. it must be possible to "trace" it by hand, looping over data and actually seeing all values working and array reversed).

Comment: Register restriction is not major problem; but can you use the stack? If you can use the stack then study how to use the stack to save (push) register values as well as to get items from the stack (pop) so you can place then into registers for loading into memory.  You should also study how to make room on the stack so you want destroy existing stack values.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic I just checked and there is no restriction about stack. Thank you I'll study about it first.

Comment: Actually 4 registers is more than enough for this task, so I would say the original intention was to ban also stack and other memory variables... 3 registers are needed for this task only (I'm ignoring fact that under certain constraints and platforms it would be possible to do this with single or two registers by compacting 3 values into them together, but at least 3 distinct values are needed for such algorithm) (on ARM probably 4 values are needed... I forgot this is not x86 question)

Comment: BTW, by "more detailed version of algorithm" I didn't mean you will try to write the code, basically you managed to turn your ill algorithm description into code, and guess what.. you got ill code. That 4 step English description was actually a good way to progress, you just didn't give it enough effort to make it perfect. I would suggest you to forget about code and get back to that description, and improve it, make it exact to the point where you can "execute" it on paper, and it "works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude and inefficient example

```
.data
        Array:  .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,32,64,128,256,512
        .equ    len.Array,.-Array
.text
        .global main
main:
        nop

        sub sp, sp, #len.Array          // save space on stack 

        ldr r1,=Array                   // Array
        mov r2, #len.Array              // length of array
        mov r3, #0                      // zero init counter Array
        1:
                ldr r0, [r1,r3]         // load word size element position x from Array
                push {r0}               // push element value into stack 
        add r3, r3, #4                  // inc Array counter by 4 since word size is 4 bytes
        cmp r3, r2                      //
        blt 1b

        // pop values off the stack  - LIFO results in reversal

        mov r3, #0                      // zero init counter Array
        2:
                pop {r0}        // pop element value from stack -  LIFO
                str r0, [r1,r3]

        add r3, r3, #4                  // inc Array counter by 4 since word size is 4 bytes                                                                                                         cmp r3, r2
        blt 2b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    add sp, sp, #len.Array          // restore stack pointer
```

GDB output:

```
(gdb) x/21d $r1
0x1102d:        1       2       3       4
0x1103d:        5       6       7       8
0x1104d:        9       10      11      12
0x1105d:        13      14      15      16
0x1106d:        32      64      128     256
0x1107d:        512


(gdb) x/21d $r1
0x1102d:        512     256     128     64
0x1103d:        32      16      15      14
0x1104d:        13      12      11      10
0x1105d:        9       8       7       6
0x1106d:        5       4       3       2
0x1107d:        1
```